# Batch Script - How to check is variable is empty

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

hope someone can help resovle the issue I'm having.
The script asks user to provide old serial number and PC location than searches a CSV file for the SN and copies the row to a text file. Once the row is in the text file is pulls the SN and Hostname and set them into 2 variables ( the actual CSV has 10 columns). The 2 variables are later passed to a log file.

Problem I have is that if the user provided SN is not in the CSV it does not get recorded, which is needed.

Been reading over google searches and tried several different but still have same issue with losing SNs not found.

Of all the IF statements this one has worked in the pass... well I think it did.

```
   If  [%aHostname%]==[]  (set oSerial=%icomputerSN%)
```

So the question I have is how do I get the script to hold the user provided variable if the variable is not in the CSV file?

sitepacket.svc

Serial # Host Name

```
2UA6492B71  0DC4A3E551DC2
MXL8361932  010E7C6B23577
MXL8321WBS  010E7C6B269C1
MXL8382H8G  0F43909049EF6
MXL8321VQ4  010E7C6B27034
MXL8331GNZ  010E7C6B7407D
MXL8331GMY  010E7C6B73961
MXL8331GPP  010E7C6B74021
MXL8331G26  010E7C6B739EF
MXL8321WFK  010E7C6B26A6B
MXL8331G1Q  010E7C6B73CF6
MXL8331GPN  010E7C6B7400C
MXL8331G3M  010E7C6B73CF7
MXL8321WBL  010E7C6B269B9
MXL8331G34  010E7C6B73D26
```

Script

```
    @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "au=TestRUN"
set "InstLog=%~dp0\AU%au%.csv"

net session >nul 2>&1

REM :: Get New workstations IP and set in var
set "ip="
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"IPv4 Address"') do set ip=%%a

:LogFileCheck
if exist %InstLog% goto :GetSN else
    echo Location,Old_SN,Old_Host,Replaced_By,New_PC_IP,New_Serial,New_Host > %InstLog%
    goto :GetSN


REM # Input field for tech to provide Old SN and old workstation location.
:GetSN  
Echo What is the old computer serial number?
set /p icomputerSN=
Echo What is the location and location number of workstation?
set /p PcLoc=


findstr /i "%icomputerSN%"  "%~dp0\Sitepacket.csv" > "%~dp0\oldsystems.txt"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-9 delims=," %%a in ("%~dp0\oldsystems.txt") DO (
   set aSerial=%%a
   set aHostname=%%b
   
   If  [%aHostname%]==[]  (set oSerial=%icomputerSN%)

)

for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%C in ('wmic bios get serialnumber') do if not defined serial set serial=%%C
set nserial=%serial: =%
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic computersystem get name'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set "nHost=%%A"


set "output=%PcLoc%,%oserial%,%oHostname%,Replace with,%nserial%,%nHost%,%IP%"

echo %output% >> %InstLog%
```

Comment: Two problems. You are assigning the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable when you do not have to. This causes the infamous delayed expansion problem. Just use: `If "%%b"=="" set "oSerial=%icomputerSN%"`. Please note the syntax I used. That is best practice. If a variable has spaces and you do not quote the variable, it will cause a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you Squashman, that help put me in the right direction. Found moving the  'IF "%%"=="" set' out of the FOR loop grouping the IF command words correctly. And found I needed an  'IF Not "%%"=="" set' was needed to still record the For loop variables.